How and when did the set brackets disappear from standard accounts of classical set theory?
On page 287 of the article On the Axiom of Extensionality, Part II, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 24, No. 4 (Dec., 1959), pp. 287-
300, the author R. O. Gandy writes:
"But, in the absence of the axiom of extensionality, there may be several distinct
classes having the same extension; and in order to develop the theory we
need to single out one of them. It would be possible to introduce a special
descriptions operator for this purpose; but it seems simpler, and closer
to the spirit of Part I, to introduce abstracts. This represents a move back
towards the set theory of Zermelo, but for our purpose that is not a disadvantage."
It is obvious that the set brackets ({ and } used for set formation) can be eliminated from classical set theory with extensionality. But how and when, i.e. by what authors and publications, did the elimination come about? Are there some published accounts of this, perhaps?

In what sense "disappeared"? They seem to me alive and well ..

@MauroALLEGRANZA In the sense that the language of set theory is now almost canonically defined as first order logic, with or without identity, plus $\in$.

Ok, you mean the set abstraction operator

But if we use it, we have to define it. I think that most set theory textbooks define it someway.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Could we not just take all ${x|\alpha(x)}$ to be terms, and simply stipulate that $\vdash Set({x|\alpha(x)})$ just if $\vdash\forall x(x\in{x|\alpha(x)}\leftrightarrow\alpha(x))$, and state the axioms as $Set({x|x\in x\wedge x\notin x})$ and so on?

@MauroALLEGRANZA I cannot recall having seen a definition of a set abstraction operator ...

See the link in my comment above for Suppes' textbook.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I saw it, so I recall that one, obviously. To me it is not reasonable. In my opinion it is better to not commit to specific denotata for terms, as ${x|x\notin x}$, which are not sets.

See e.g. George Tourlakis, Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 2: Set Theory (Cambridge UP, 2003), page 126 for the set term $y = { x : F  }$ and page 71 for the logical machinery of definitions (extension by definition of the language).

The "abstraction notation" evolved from Peanesque original through W&R's Principia (1910-13) where we have: $(\alpha = \hat z (\phi z)) \equiv \forall x( x \in \alpha \equiv \phi x)$. See page 188: "treating $\hat z (\psi z)$ as the class determined by [the propositional function] $\psi \hat z$".

That is nice to know. But it is not clear to me that Peano's propositional function $\psi\hat{z}$ is in less need of analysis than his class $\hat{z}(\psi z)$. Incidentally, as you know, Quine uses that Peanesque notation for classes, or sets.
